# How do I create space on the top of my stackview for the status bar without using a fixed height?

Tags: ios, swift3, ios-autolayout, stackview

I am using Swift 3 and stack views (aka auto layout) with constraints.

At the moment my app's header and the standard iOS status bar is overlapping.

I DON'T want to create another empty stack with a fixed height because I'm trying to keep it as responsive as possible for now and the future (for iPhone 5 the height probably like 50px and iPhone 7 it is probably like 200px).

Is there some sort of logical solution from the interface, or is the only way to do it to load some custom code in the;

`override func viewDidLoad()` section?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply NSLayoutConstraint:

**1)** **Create an autolayout top leading constraint** between super view and stack view - CTRL drag it to your view controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var topLeadingOffsetFromStatusBar: NSAutolayoutConstraint!
```

**2)** **Set its constant** to dynamic value:

```
let offset = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
self.topLeadingOffsetFromStatusBar.constant = offset
```

Comment: That did not work unfortunately - the latest version of Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a) and Swift 3 - changed the code slightly with updated keywords and built successfully but then it crashed with error: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: I am using swift3 as well. I assumed you use swift2. Do you want me to retype the code to swift3 for you?

Comment: Aha, well I already did when it gave me the error:

    @IBOutlet weak var topLeadingOffsetFromStatusBar: NSLayoutConstraint!
    let offset = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height

and then

        self.topLeadingOffsetFromStatusBar.constant = offset ,,.. in the viewDidLoad()